# Extract month and year from postgresql

Tags: postgresql, extract

I have a table with a date column.

```
+-----------+-------+
|   Date    | xx    |
+-----------+-------+
| 6/29/2020 |   45  |
| 3/6/2018  |   89  |
| 6/30/2020 |   69  |
| 5/6/2019  |   45  |
| 5/12/2019 |   89  |
| 6/4/2019  |   72  |
| 4/27/2019 |   69  |
| 6/29/2020 |   48  |
| 6/30/2020 |   36  |
| 6/4/2019  |   57  |
+-----------+-------+
```

I need to extract month and year from this column and add as 2 separate columns and summarize by summation of 'xx'.

```
+------+-------+-----+
| Year | Month | Sums|
+------+-------+-----+
| 2018 |     3 |  89 |
| 2019 |     4 |  69 |
| 2019 |     5 | 134 |
| 2019 |     6 | 129 |
| 2020 |     6 | 198 |
+------+-------+-----+
```

I have tried below but is does not summarize on a yearly and monthly basis.

```
select extract(month from datee), extract(year from datee), sum(xx) sums from table1
group by datee
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "does not work"? Do you get an error? The wrong results?

Comment: I want to add 2 separate columns. From above query, when I use group by clause, it does not summarize from month and year. It summarizes in a daily basis

Answer (score 0):

Look, I run this query `select extract(month from col) from table1;` and it works.
In your query column has a name 'datee'. Did you sure that is right?
Also, if your table/column name contains capital letters, then you need to place it between single quotes ''.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by the year and month you've extracted, not by the "raw" date:

```
SELECT   EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datee), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datee), SUM(xx) sums
FROM     table1
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datee), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datee)
```

Answer (score 0):

The objective here is convert the `date` to required group by format - in this case year-month.

```
select to_char(datee, 'YYYY-MM'), sum(counter) from date_mon_y group by to_char(datee, 'YYYY-MM');
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it